# How much funding (if any) does the CDC receive from private industry?

Tags: united-states, funding, cdc

Does the CDC receive funding from pharmaceutical companies, or any other non-government agency or company? If so, how much money and from whom?

Answer (score 7):

The [CDC itself is federal agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centers_for_Disease_Control_and_Prevention#Budget_and_operations), so as such it receives all of its funding from the Federal Budget.

Unless you want to get into (more or less philosophical) discussions where the Federal Budget money comes from, that's all there is to say on this matter. And if you do want to ask about the latter, please ask separately.

Besides the CDC, there exists a CDC Foundation, which is indeed a non-profit organization that does take private donations

> The CDC Foundation operates independently from CDC as a private, nonprofit 501(c)(3) organization incorporated in the State of Georgia. The creation of the Foundation was authorized by section 399F of the Public Health Service Act to support the mission of CDC in partnership with the private sector, including organizations, foundations, businesses, educational groups, and individuals.

If you want details about the funding of this CDC Foundation, please be more specific with your question.

Comment: The only thing I could thing the OP was asking was paying for drug trials at the FDA.  Really don't understand the question to be honest.  But +1 for the CDC foundation.  There are a few in government, like if you want to contribute on your taxes to public finance elections.

Comment: @KDog: I guess the OP might have confused the CDC with the FDA, which is a different agency. That would be unusual, since [more people have heard of the FDA than of the CDC](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5433718/).

Comment: @KDog I think the most likely explanation is that the OP is working the "CDC is Pharma's pocket" anti-vax angle.

Comment: @motosubatsu or that the CDC is a hospital

Answer (score 3):

As Fizz's answer points out the CDC is a federal agency and as such is funded by Congressional Appropriations - however this is not the *only* source of funding.

Looking at the [most recent data at time of writing](https://www.cdc.gov/partners/gift-funding.html) (FY 2018) the CDC received direct gifts of $11,477,767 - mostly from Universities and other charitable foundations. The biggest donor was [GAVI Alliance](https://www.gavi.org/) at just over $4 million but you can read the full list [here](https://www.cdc.gov/partners/pdf/2018-Gifts-to-CDC-final.pdf) and $15,083,198 in gifts from the CDC Foundation.

So that's a total of about $26,560,965 coming from non-governmental sources, which at first glance might sound like a lot of money. When compared with the $8,245,808,000 received from the aforementioned congressional appropriations its, erm, not. It is in fact just 0.32% of the total funding for FY 2018.